# Firebase CLI redirect_uri_mismatch on login

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

Cannot log in to the firebase CLI.

```
firebase login
```

Generates the following error prompt in browser:

```
The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:9005, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/...?project=... to update the authorized redirect URIs.
```

Obesrvations:

- http://localhost:9005 and every single possible variation including trailing slashes and the https protocol is listed under the web oauth client
- the `?project=xxx` is pointing towards the wrong project ID

`firebase login:ci --interactive` and `firebase login --reauth` yield exactly the same result.

The github issue is being ignored. I'd really like to use the cloud function feature

Comment: Try `firebase login --no-localhost`?

Comment: @MichaelBleigh I tried it, but --no-localhost is not allowed for web applications. Looking at the source code of the CLI the problem turned out to be that i had exported $FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID in my .bash_profile file for a previous project

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the following command instead:

```
firebase login --no-localhost
```